# Jquery remove element from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This should be fun to solve :)

In a text field I have the value `Apple,Peach,Banana`.

Using Jquery I created an array from that CSV.

In HTML I have a list of the fruits with a "remove" option next to each one. When I click "remove" I want to remove the corresponding fruit from the list and the text field.

I'm missing one function that will remove fruits from the array. What function should I use?

http://jsfiddle.net/BXWqK/19/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should use [JavaScript Splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

```
fruits_array.splice(fruit_index,1);
```

You also need to change:

`$('#fruits').val(skills_array.join(','));` to `$('#fruits').val(fruits_array.join(','));`

Comment: [Here's the MDN docs for `Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 6):

```
    var A=['Apple','Peach','Banana'];

    A.splice(1,1)

// removes 1 item starting at index[1] 
// returns ['Peach'];
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution is correct, but it doesn't mention that you shouldn't use indexOf to get the fruit_index to remove, because [IndexOf not Supported in IE8 Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848097/indexof-not-supported-in-ie8-browser)

You should use:

```
fruits_array.splice($.inArray('Peach', fruits_array), 1);
```