# IndexOf not Supported in IE8 Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, telerik

I have cascaded dropdown in my application, cascaded using jquery, now my problem is it is working smoothly with IE9, Firefox, Opera and Safari but does not work with any of browsers like IE7,IE8 etc.

I surfed for the problem and found that error is due to indexOf in my jquery code, i tried it by removing indexOf but still it is giving the same error..

Note: Is there any work around in telerik script to remove indexOf, coz new only i can find indexOf in their script.

Below is the Code:

```
function OnClientSelectedIndexChanged(sender, eventArgs) {
var senderId = sender.get_id().toString();

var uniqueName = senderId.substring(senderId.lastIndexOf('_'), senderId.length);

if(senderId.indexOf("drpdwnCondition") > 0)
{
   return false;
}

var selectedItem = eventArgs.get_item();
var selectedValue = selectedItem.get_value().split('_');
$.ajax({ type: "POST", async: true,
    url: "/SalesRepresentativeMonitoring.aspx/GetData", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: "{value:" + JSON.stringify(selectedValue[1]) + "}", dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        var resultAsJson = msg.d // your return result is JS array
        // Now you can loop over the array to get each object
        var cnditionCombo = $find("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_radDock_C_Filter_drpdwnCondition" + uniqueName.toString());
        cnditionCombo.clearSelection();
        cnditionCombo.trackChanges();
        cnditionCombo.clearItems();
        for (var i in resultAsJson) {
            //alert(resultAsJson[i]);
            var item = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();
            item.set_text(resultAsJson[i]);
            item.set_value(resultAsJson[i]);
            cnditionCombo.get_items().add(item);
        }
        var itemAtIndex = cnditionCombo.get_items().getItem(0);  //get item in detailCB
        itemAtIndex.select();
        cnditionCombo.commitChanges();
    }
});
```

}

Thanking you..

Comment: Could you please post your code.

Comment: AFAIK, indexOf works well in ie7 and 8. Please show some code

Comment: @Archer He said that it did work in ie9, and not 7+8 :) Anyways, it should be working in all of them

Comment: The `indexOf` method of Arrays is not implemented in IE < 9, so I assume that's what the OP is referring to.

Comment: Correct - I take it back.  However, like I said about removing it leaving the same error means that it is not the problem.

Comment: I was refering to the string.indexOf though. As far as arrays are concerned, you can always use jquereys $.inArray

Comment: indexOf is working but while using ie8 i am getting error like "Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf'"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `indexOf()` method of `Array`s is not implemented in IE < 9. As you're using jQuery you can make use of the `$.inArray()`, e.g.

```
var arr = ["foo", "bar", "baz"],
    bazIndex = $.inArray("baz", arr), // 2
    doesntExistIndex = $.inArray("notThere", arr); // -1
```

Here's the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/.

Answer (score 22):

The [documentation for `indexOf` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) includes a pollyfill that will add support in browsers that don't support JavaScript 1.6.

You can drop it in to avoid having to rewrite the existing code.

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function (searchElement /*, fromIndex */ ) {
        "use strict";
        if (this == null) {
            throw new TypeError();
        }
        var t = Object(this);
        var len = t.length >>> 0;
        if (len === 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        var n = 0;
        if (arguments.length > 0) {
            n = Number(arguments[1]);
            if (n != n) { // shortcut for verifying if it's NaN
                n = 0;
            } else if (n != 0 && n != Infinity && n != -Infinity) {
                n = (n > 0 || -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(n));
            }
        }
        if (n >= len) {
            return -1;
        }
        var k = n >= 0 ? n : Math.max(len - Math.abs(n), 0);
        for (; k < len; k++) {
            if (k in t && t[k] === searchElement) {
                return k;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```