# Jquery how to shuffle the array value? when toggleClass?

Tags: jquery

I have 5 `li` elements, while I click on each of them, I am adding a class name `on` and push it into an array. I would like to remove the item from the object when a user is clicking again.

```
<ul>
  <li class="on" data-index="3">add 3</li>
  <li data-index="4">add 4</li>
  <li data-index="5">add 5</li>
  <li class="on" data-index="6">add 6</li>
</ul>
```

When a user clicks on a `li` I add a class called `on` and push the value into an array and sort the array after I pushed the item.

If a user clicks again on the `li` I can't remove the value from the array, because of the sort. Is there a way I can achieve this?

I don't have any idea to do the functionality regarding this.. any one can help me? I tried with splice, but no result.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234269/jquery-remove-element-from-array. Also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596089/how-to-add-and-remove-array-value-in-jquery

Comment: When you say 'pushing the value to an array' do you mean the `data-index` value, or the text value?

Comment: How about posting your jQuery?

Comment: could it be a conflict between your class .on and the JQuery method `.on()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `delete arr[index]` syntax to remove any element from array. 
Try this:

```
var arr = {};
$('ul > li').click(function () {
   $(this).toggleClass('on');
    if ($(this).hasClass('on')) {
       arr[$(this).attr('data-index')] = $(this).html();
    } else {
        delete arr[$(this).attr('data-index')];
    }
    console.log(sortObj(arr));
});

function sortObj(arr){
    var sortedKeys = new Array();
    var sortedObj = {};

    for (var i in arr){
        sortedKeys.push(i);
    }
    sortedKeys.sort();

    for (var i in sortedKeys){
        sortedObj[sortedKeys[i]] = arr[sortedKeys[i]];
    }
    return sortedObj;
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/codef0rmer/AEYtq/1/

Comment: he want to sort his array, you don't sort.